# Logstash "date" filter doesn't replace @timestamp

Tags: apache, logstash

For some reason when I try to replace the @timestamp field in my apache access log events, it doesn't work. For Nginx it did work with the same date format.

This is my log date format : [10/Dec/2014:13:01:06 -0500]

This is my logstash.conf -

```
if [type] == "apache" {
   grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:time}\] \"(?:%{WORD:method} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)" }
        add_tag => [ "apache", "grokked" ]
        }
   date {
        match => [ "[time]" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        locale => "en"
        add_tag => ["date_filtered"]
        }
     }
```

The @timestamp field stays in this format - 2014-12-10T18:01:06.000Z

**update:**
This is the full configuration -

There are no errors in the logs, only logstash startup log lines.

My logstash configuration file is as follows :

```
input {
redis {
        host => "<redis_server>"
        port => "<redis_port>"
        data_type => 'list'
        key => 'logstash'
        type => 'redis'
        threads => 300
 }

filter {


multiline {
        pattern => "(^\s)|(^INFO.+)|(^SEVERE.+)"
        what => "previous"
        add_tag => ["multiline"]
        stream_identity => '%{host}.%{file}.%{type}'

   }

if [type] == "apache" {
   grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:time}\] \"(?:%{WORD:method} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)" }
        add_tag => [ "apache", "grokked" ]
        }
   date {
        match => [ "[time]" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        locale => "en"
        add_tag => ["date_filtered"]
        }
     }
}

output {

  elasticsearch {
    host => "<ES_server>"
    port => "9300"
    cluster => "elasticsearch"
    embedded => false
    node_name => "logstash"
   }
}
```

And the result is :

[image]

When it should actually be :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see `time` in your grok filter ? how are you extracting time out of your `message` ?

Comment: @Vaibhav: `\[%{HTTPDATE:time}\]` is included in the pattern.

Comment: I'm extracting it in the grok filter - \[%{HTTPDATE:time}\]

Comment: @user3323914: Not sure exactly what you're asking here. Your last statement indicates that you're expecting the timestamp field to have another _format_, but the format of that field is _always_ ISO8601 as in your example. Or is the problem that the date filter fails to parse the timestamps? If so the log will contain an error message that points in the right direction.

Comment: @MagnusBäck, Thanks. If I understand you correctly, these are 2 different formats? -  [10/Dec/2014:13:01:06 -0500]  and 2014-12-10T18:01:06.000Z ?  Do you know what should I do to make it work with the current format? Thanks!

Comment: The pattern in your date plugin looks okay. Repeating what I said earlier: If the problem is that the date filter fails to parse your timestamp there will be additional information in the logs. Now, if you provide a complete log line, configuration, and indicate exactly what the problem is it should be quite easy to help out.

Comment: @MagnusBäck - I updated my question with all the information.

Comment: It's still not clear what your problem is. Is the date from the logfile not getting parsed into the `@timestamp` field, or is it the date format of the `@timestamp` field that you don't like?

Comment: @MagnusBäck- the `@timestamp` field is not the way I expected it to be (it should be like the "time" field)

Comment: Do you means you want to change the timestamp format to your locate time like '2014-12-10T13:01:06.000 -05:00'

Comment: yes, am I missing something basic here?

Comment: Formatting is supported in Kibana 4.   https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/968

Answer (score 0):

On average, only 1/1000 logs are processed at millisecond=000 as shown in your @timestamp.

Can you guess what happens when you pass HH:mm:ss into date{}?  That's right - with no millisecond information provided in the input, it's set to 000.

So, I think your date{} stanza is working just fine.

You can confirm this by looking for the tag "date_filtered" in your output; the tag will only be added if the date{} succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question was not about the milliseconds, but the difference between the hours in my fields. The `@timestamp` field says its 11:34 while the `time` field says 06:34. Again, I feel like im missing something obvious here but I would like to figure it out entirely. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that its a timezone difference, oops! thanks!